# ¿Cómo puedo obtener una respuesta con dos cifras decimales de cero (ej: 42.00)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por ejemplo, si en el siguiente código necesito que mi respuesta sea `[85.00,47.00,66.00]`, pero solo obtengo `[85.0,47.0,66.0]`

¿como puedo hacer?

```
n=2
L=[83.00,45.00,64.00]
M=[]
for i in L:
    v=i+n
    M.append(round(v,2))
print(M)
```

Answer (score 3):

Como comprenderas, 83.0 y 83.00 son el mismo valor, asi que el problema se trata sólo de *mostrarlo* con dos decimales.

Para eso puedes formatear el valor de punto flotante usando "%.2f".

El ".2" indica que siempre hay que producir dos decimales después de la coma.

Entonces

```
print("%.2f" % 93.0)
```

produce

```
93.00
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Utilizar format para "formatearlo" a dos unidades decimales.
2. En caso de necesitar almacenarlos como float, si le aplicas el método float() te los redondeará a un decimal, por lo que tienes que tener en cuenta que lo almacenado en la lista son strings.

**Código**:

```
n=2

L=[83.00,45.00,64.00]

M = []

for i in L:
    v=i+n
    two_decimals = '{:.2f}'.format(v)
    M.append(two_decimals)
```

**Resultado**:

```
$ -> python3 g.py
85.00
<class 'str'>
47.00
<class 'str'>
66.00
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Pero eso hace un arreglo de objetos (strings), no de floats...

Comment: No ha especificado el tipo de dato.

Comment: Bueno, el resultado no trae apóstrofes, me imagino que eso nos daría una idea

Comment: Sí, por supuesto. Entiendo que es mejor almacenar de alguna forma los datos en una lista como parece que es lo que necesita por al append que se hace en lugar de imprimir parte a parte los caracteres. Hemos presentado varias formas de hacerlo así que puede escoger la que más se adapte a lo que necesite.

Comment: Aunque creo que lo que quiere hacer, no se puede, o no se me ocurre cómo, si imprimes la variable de la lista y trae floats, los va a presentar con el punto decimal y un cero. No sé si usando el otro tipo (creo que es Decimal, no le recuerdo con claridad) pueda hacerse

Answer (score 0):

No creo que haya forma de que al desplegar la lista `M` te regrese números flotantes con dos decimales. La solución que te pone @Adrian te regresa una lista de strings.

Lo que tienes que hacer, en todo caso, una vez que tienes tu `M`, es simular lo que quieres hacer, algo así como:

```
arr = [85.0,47.0,66.0]

print('[', end='')
for i in range(len(arr)):
    print(f'{arr[i]:.2f}', end='')
    if i < len(arr)-1:
        print(',', end='')
print(']')
```

Resultado:

```
[85.00,47.00,66.00]
```

Está horrible la solución, pero... imprime lo que quieres